# How to Update Columns dynamically in kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui

We are using kendo grid with angularjs, am trying to update columns data dynamically, but it is not updating column info. Below is the code.

```
function loadSelectRowsGrid(gridData) {

    var selectRowsGridID = "#rowsConfiguration-Grid";
    var grid = $(selectRowsGridID).data("kendoGrid");
    if (grid !== undefined && grid.dataSource.options.data !== null) {
        grid.destroy();
       }

    pcService.rowConfiguration.configurationItem = [];
    pcService.columnCollection.columns = [];

    var maxColumnCount = 3
    for (var i = 0 ; i <= maxColumnCount; i++) {
        if (i != 0) {
            //var columnObject = { "field": gridData.columnData[i].field };//+ "," + "title:" + localizationService.GetLocalizedText(gridData.columnData[i].field);
            var columnObject = { "field": gridData.columnData[i].field, "title": localizationService.GetLocalizedText(gridData.columnData[i].field) };
            pcService.columnCollection.columns.push(columnObject);
        }
        else {

        }
    }

    $(selectRowsGridID).kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            data: gridData.gridData,
        },
        columns: pcService.columnCollection.columns, //gridData.columnData, 
        scrollable: false,
    });
```

}

Please help me how to update column data dynamically.

**UPDATE**

I found the reason why this is happening, because I have used kendo window where when I close the popup but it is still sitting in DOM. How to destory kendowindow popup? Below is my syntax:

```
var selectRowsDialog = $("#select-Rows-dialog").kendoWindow({ 
    width: "800px", 
    title: "Select rows", 
    autoOpen: false, 
    closable: true, 
    modal: true, 
    visible: false, 
    close: function () { }, }).data("kendoWindow").center().open();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I destroy a kendo widget:

```
$("#wnd")
    .detach()
    .data("kendoWindow")
        .close()
        .destroy();
```

First I [`detach`](https://api.jquery.com/detach/) it from the DOM, then I [`destroy`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window#methods-destroy) it.

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/oLuQU)